# I want to be able to upload files using jqgrid's add/edit dialgoue box

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I want to upload files when adding or modifying records to a jqgrid. How is it possible? Is there some way to tinker with its Add/Edit Dialogue boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the domos for the customised Edit Dialog? http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnet.aspx

Click on Edit, Add, Delete Rows in the menu and select Edit Form Types, which shows you how to control which controls are displayed for editing. You could use a file upload control. You will probably have to change the enctype of the post to "multipart/form-data". Not sure how to do that with jqgrid, but it shouldn't be too hard.